# Android Facebook Share Dialog's content not shown in home page

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I using "ShareDialog" for sharing a link from my app to Facebook wall. When i post a link, it shows the content only in user's timeline and not in home page. What i'm doing wrong?

I'm doing something like that:

```
// This is how i invokes the shareDialog
FacebookDialog shareDialog = createShareDialogBuilderForLink().build();

private FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder createShareDialogBuilderForLink() {
    return new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
    .setPicture("picture url")
    .setName("name")
    .setLink("link url");
}
```

User's timeline:

[image]

Home page:

[image]

In home page only shows the name of the app which take it from the link i setted(app in google play) without showing the content of the link(descriptiion, name, Caption...).

Comment: How can i make the link in Facebook home page to take the content from share Dialog but not from the link.

Comment: I think when you set a link it overrides all of the other properties...

Comment: Can u find any solution for this? I am in the same issue

Comment: Mmm no i leave it that way...

Answer (score 1):

Its because the user chose to not share the link publicly, do you see the little lock icon alongside the time the link was shared? It shows that link is not shared publicly, if its public the icon changes to globe icon.

**What to do now?**

1) I don't know whether Facebook API allows to set permissions on the post but you can try, [see API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/permissions).

2) Many users by default set the share permission to private, see whether your account has it private by default by going in Facebook settings.

Comment: This is not the reason. I just tested the same thing with a link shared publicly and it shows the same behavior reported by the asker.

Comment: Oh perhaps it is! As i said that you need to set permissions from Facebook API, here is the link to Facebook API documentation that says so, read it full https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/permissions

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
    ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentDescription("Description")
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("Url"))
            .build();

    shareDialog.show(linkContent);
}
```